# Angular 2 Report with 3 or more REST calls

Tags: rest, http, angular

I am trying to create a customized report / page that is built by pulling in three different tables - Order Header, Order Detail, and Job Ticket. I can get this to work fine in regular javascript (process all the REST calls and then generate HTML code to insert into the DOM) but I am unable to figure out what the approach should be in Angular 2. The table dependency is Order Header -> Order Detail -> Job Ticket. I have three services, one for each REST call chained (see following code). I am struggling with how to get the data from all three tables to appear on the HTML template properly, where the Order Header information is on one line and the sub-detail lines beneath each order header.

I have tried something like this in my app.component:

```
this.ordersService.getOrders()
     .subscribe(data => {
        this.orders = data;
    for (let i in this.orders) {

    this.detailsService.getDetails(this.orders[i].id)
        .subscribe(data => {
              this.details = data;

              for (let ii in this.details) {
                  this.jobTicketService.getJobTicket(this.orders[i].id, this.details[ii].id)
                              .subscribe(data => {
                                      // process data
                                   }
```

app.component.html - (not formatted to final form, just for testing)

```
<div id="title">
    {{title}}
</div>
<div *ngFor="let order of orders">
    {{order.Title}}
    <div *ngFor="let detail of details">
        {{detail.Description}}
        <div *ngFor="let jobTicket of jobTickets">
            {{activity.Title}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I get is this:

```
Order 1
    Order 4 Detail Id 5          (last record in details array)
        Job Ticket Order 4 Detail Id 5 Activity 1
        Job Ticket Order 4 Detail Id 5 Activity 2
Order 2
    Order 4 Detail Id 5          (last record in details array)
        Job Ticket Order 4 Detail Id 5 Activity 1
        Job Ticket Order 4 Detail Id 5 Activity 2
Order 3
    Order 4 Detail Id 5          (last record in details array)
        Job Ticket Order 4 Detail Id 5 Activity 1
        Job Ticket Order 4 Detail Id 5 Activity 2
Order 4
    Order 4 Detail Id 5
        Job Ticket Order 4 Detail Id 5 Activity 1
        Job Ticket Order 4 Detail Id 5 Activity 2
```

I can tell I am getting data when I output values to console.log but do not seem to understand how to get it linked to the template properly.

Here is a sample of how I need it to eventually look:

Order: 1    Description: Custom product     Client: ABC Corp.

```
  Item: Product123       Qty. 3       Production Status: In Shipping
```

Order: 2    Description: Special Order      Client: ACME Corp.

```
  Item: Product234       Qty. 1       Production Status: In Production
  Item: Product123       Qty. 3       Production Status: In Shipping
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are these **Order Header -> Order Detail -> Job Ticket** three in separate components? More information needed. Sample layout(wire frame) how are you handling service call for a single object.

Comment: There is only one component - app.component - with each REST call in its own service.

Comment: what is the trouble that you are facing?

Comment: The main issue I am struggling with is keeping the data relationship correct at rendering. I have updated the question to provide clarification on HTML template.

Comment: how are these data retrieved from the database using which you can optimize?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. I am unable to gain access to the underlying database and create an SQL view (that would sure be nice!) so I have to handle the relationships on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public get data$() {
   return this.ordersService.getOrders()
     .switchMap(orders => Observable
        .forkJoin(...orders.map(order => this.detailsService.getDetails(order.id))
          .mergeMap(([...details]) => Observable
            .forkJoin(details.map(detail => this.jobTicketService.getJobTicket(detail.id))
              .mergeMap(([...tickets]) => {orders, details, tickets})
            )
          )
        )
     );
}
```

And if you subscripte to it with:

```
this.data$.subscribe(data => {
  // process your data (should be { orders: orders, details: details, tickets: tickets})
})
```

Note: Just made this up, its untested

In your template you can use it (example):

```
<div *ngFor="let order of (data$ | async)?.orders)>your order</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try.

Comment: Could you provide a brief explanation on how you see this working through the various switchMap, forkJoin, mergeMap operators?